# Controllers and ons-page not working in stable, OnsenUI dev is broken

Tags: onsen-ui

I would really like to use OnsenUi, but the Issue #22 on Github is preventing me from using it in my app.

I tried merging in the navigation_binding branch on master, but get too many conflicts. I also compiled the dev branch, but it barfs out with this error message:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ScreenStackProvider <- ScreenStack <- Screen <- onsScreenDirective

Any help on using the dev branch? Or could you guys please try to release a more fresh stable release with the navigation_binding fix in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried merging in the navigation_binding branch on master, but get too many conflicts. 
>   I also compiled the dev branch, but it barfs out with this error message:

Please try to checkout the latest dev branch, we believe the error was fixed.

> Or could you guys please try to release a more fresh stable release with the >navigation_binding fix in it?

We will not modify and release navigation_binding branch anymore. Please use dev branch.

If you have any problem, please post on Onen UI Github issues.

https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues

Thank you.

Kind regards,
Onsen UI Team